# PHP, why not getting value text likes &lt;body&gt; from url passing by GET or POST request

Tags: php

In PHP, why am I not getting value text likes `<heading>` from url passing by `GET` or `POST` request. I can see these value from browser address URL, when I passing by GET request.

It's URL view:

```
test_validate.php?subject=JavaEE&correct1=&lt;heading&gt;&correct2=&lt;lb&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You used HTML entities in the URL instead of [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Plus `&` is a reserved keyword to define arguments in a GET request.

You have to encode the `<` and `>` characters :

- `<` must be replaced by `%3C`
- `>` must be replaced by `%3E`

Try with the following URL:

```
test_validate.php?subject=JavaEE&correct1=%3Cheading%3E&correct2=%3Clb%3E
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem another bad way)), thanks for %3C,%3E I will know in future

Comment: Ok, you can post your solution as an answer, in order to help other people who may encounter the same problem.